# Character not moving in horizontal axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm writing a `2D` platform game with `Visual Studio Code` and `Unity`. So far, I have established the animations that I will use later in the main character and the enemy. With the main character I have defined the "horizontal move" and the "vertical move". However when I run the game, the character moves up, but it doesn't move left or right.

This is the code that I have for the main character:

```
public class Hero : Monobehaviour 
 
 { 
    public float vel =10f;
    public Animator anim;
    private Vector2 moveVelocity; 
    float horizontalMove = 0f; 

    private Rigidbody2D rb; 

  void Start()
  {
     rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
  }

  void Update() 
  {
   horizontalMove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * vel;
   Vector2 moveInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
   moveVelocity = moveInput.normalized * vel;
  }

  void FixedUpdate()
  {
    Vector2 v = new Vector2 (vel, 0);
    rb.velocity = v;
    rb.MovePosition(rb.position + moveVelocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);       
  }

}
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Did you mean to use `CrossPlatformInputManager` instead of `Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")`? Because there is little point in writing `Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")` instead of `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D)`

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you change your code to this:

```
    void Update() 
      {
       if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
          {
          rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector2.right * (vel*Time.deltaTime));
          }
           else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
              {
              rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector2.left * (vel*Time.deltaTime));
              }
      }
```

Since you have a rigidbody attached to your game object, it would make sense to add relative force to the object when a user presses D/A instead of just changing the object's transform  position. This should work.

Comment: Hello, i made some adjustments to the initial code. I'm still using Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") because later i needed to rotate the object in the X axis. I tried to use some of the suggested code for "jump" but it doesn't seem to work. The code with a new public float "jump" ended looking like this                                                                                                                              if               (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))  
                  {      rb.AddForce(new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jump));   
                }   
        
               }

Comment: @MauricioVázquez My answer defined horizontal movement, not jumping because you said that your game object was not able to "move left or right". If you also need jumping when the player presses space, use `rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector2.up* (vel*Time.deltaTime));`

Answer (score -1):

Essentially, you can set the horizontal move up in the input manager under Edit > project settings > input. Double-check if the horizontal axis is set up to the left and right button.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.